# Download WIA SDK or DLLs (for camera capture)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, wia

**Where are the WIA dlls?**

I cannot find any WIA (DLLs/SDK) download on google, microsoft.com, MSDN ... `wiascr.dll` is not on my machine anywhere. The only place I got `Interop.WIA.dll` and `wiaaut.dll` from was another program installed that *happened* to use it.

Have I got the wrong end of the stick here, guys? [Pages like this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630367%28v=vs.85%29.aspxhttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630367%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) refer to it, but there's no link. Most of my searches I tend to end up at this [12 year old page about it](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2303/WIA-Scripting-and-NET). Looks good, but it does just seem to assume you have these dlls already, which leads me to wonder:

**Is there a better way of doing camera capture I should be using?**

What I really expected was that it'd be part of my VS installation and I'd just type WIA into the Reference Manager and be done.

Comment: It is an integral part of Windows and pre-installed since Vista.  WIA 2.0 was back-ported to XP as well and they made an installer available.  That installer has been removed however, it won't come back.  Can't be the issue, VS2012 will not install on XP.  You need to get your machine fixed, not on topic here.

Comment: So you're saying `wiascr.dll` should be in windows (7) somewhere?

Comment: Wiascr.dll is replaced by wiaaut.dll, the one you should be using.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hans, i was about to go crazy ^^"