# How to preview and then take a Camera picture

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I asked a question (with no answers!) about WIA yesterday so have gone for a more generic question today. I'm under the distinct impression that WIA is no longer intended for camera capture.
My question is: **so how do you take a camera snap in C#, Winforms, .net?**

Comment: What do you mean with a "Camera snap"? Do you mean a printscreen or take a photo with an attached camera?

Comment: This question contains the answer to your problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113426/how-do-i-connect-to-a-usb-webcam-in-net

Comment: I mean take a picture with the attached camera

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy so you're saying use DirectShow? (I've seen that question on my extensive search, and most answers say use WIA - which I've had no luck trying to use)

Comment: @noelicus The accepted answer uses WIA

Comment: it doesn't have an accepted answer!

Comment: And you still use WIA today.

Comment: @noelicus sorry, the top rated answer

Comment: Then please, please could somebody answer [my other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209829/download-wia-sdk-or-dlls-for-camera-capture)?

Comment: @noelicus from msdn - "WIA is an API included in Windows that aims to unify the acquisition of images from all kinds of devices, including scanners and cameras." Have you tried downloading the examples?

Comment: I've read it "doesn't support video since windows vista" - which could mean "no webcams". I've not been able to find any C# WIA microsoft examples ... do you have a link?

Comment: For example ... [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms629844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is in C++ and then has a note "WIA does not support video devices...". It's as if nobody else has a requirement to use the webcam!!